# How to reduce lag when sending data over pipes for GUI textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, multiprocessing, pipe

I have a process that continuously reads data off of a bus and sends the data (converted into strings) via a pipe to a GUI. I'm using multiple processes (multipleprocessing library) where the GUI and the read process are separate.

The GUI then takes that data (strings) and displays them in a textbox. I want to read incoming data to the GUI at 1ms intervals (after(1, read_data)). However, I think the strings are too big so the data in the pipes are transmitting too slowly and therefore causing the textbox to display the data too slowly. I'm trying to get live data of the information on the bus so fast timing is necessary.

bus data --> read process --> GUI (GUI prints the data strings in a textbox)

How do I reduce the lag or slowdown between the reading process and the GUI? How long does it take for data to travel through a pipe?

An example of a string would be: 
"######################################################################\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n######################################################################\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n######################################################################\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n######################################################################\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n"

I've tried sending the data as the entire string. I've also tried sending it in chunks but it's still slow because both ends of the pipes have to perform multiple iterations of the reads or writes.

What can I do to maintain fast sending and receiving (within the 0.1ms to 4ms range)?

**edit:
I'm updating a textbox in Tkinter every 25ms with the data received.**

Comment: What would even be the point in updating a textbox "within the 0.1ms to 4ms range"?  Your monitor isn't physically capable of updating its display that fast!

Comment: The sending and receiving is "within 0.1ms to 4ms range" but my textbox only updates every 25ms. I'm doing fast send/receives to guarantee that I'm capturing all of my data. So anytime I'm updating my textbox, I know that my data is accurate.